# Enable Excerpt field inside the post editor for pages

Tags: wp-admin

How can I edit the post excerpt for pages? This field is visible inside the post editor for single posts only. Not for pages.

Is there any option to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Adding excerpt for page
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```